# How to free the memory space in CUDA texture object returned from a function wrapper?

Tags: c++, memory-management, cuda, textures

Suppose I have a helper function to facilitate the process of creating CUDA objects from another structured array (`mxArray` from Matlab, specifically).

It will be a function like this:

```
cudaTextureObject_t  tex_output = mxArrayToTexture(mxArray * inputMxArray);
```

This function will check the type and size of `inputMxArray`, hide the details of creating `cudaArray_t`, texture resource, description, etc. It works great when I have a dozen of texture objects to create with different dimension, size and type. However, I am not sure how to clean up and free the memory afterwards.

Typically, I use `cudaDestroyTextureObject(tex_output)` to destroy the texture object. But how do I free the memory allocated to the `cudaArray_t` within the texture object?

I checked the available memory on GPU before and after each time I run the code, and there is definitively  ~300Mb of memory not being released. I suppose not using `cudaFreeArray()` on the `cudaArray_t` hidden within the  helper function is the issue. Eventually the device will run out of memory space if I don't fix this problem.

Any suggestions to improve this approach to have a helper function to create CUDA texture objects and free up the memory correctly?

Comment: RAII. use a custom struct with appropriate destructor. use unique_ptr with custom deleter. that's not really a cuda-specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get back the underlying `cudaArray_t` using [`cudaGetTextureObjectResourceDesc()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT_1g4ac6e3f033c356ecc4ab6fb85154f066).

I.e.:

```cpp
void destroyAndFreeTexture(cudaTextureObject_t tex) {
    cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
    ERR_CHECK(cudaGetTextureObjectResourceDesc(&resDesc, tex));
    ERR_CHECK(cudaDestroyTextureObject(tex));

    if (resDesc.resType == cudaResourceTypeArray) {
        cudaArray_t mem = resDesc.res.array.array;
        ERR_CHECK(cudaFreeArray(mem));
    }
    else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

where `ERR_CHECK` should be substituted by whatever error checking scheme you use for the CUDA runtime API.

Depending on the context, you might want to error/throw and exception in the `else` branch or just also handle the other options (`cudaResourceTypeMipmappedArray`, `cudaResourceTypeLinear` and `cudaResourceTypePitch2D`).

I personally would also use this as the destructor of some C++ RAII class, as [Abator Abetor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5206464/abator-abetor)  proposed in the comments.

Comment: This function works great. But I have another question, some of the texture objects are stored as the fields of a structure. If I use this function on the structure field directly, i.e `destroyAndFreeTexture(someStructure.textureObject)`, it caused the access violation crash. How to do this properly in the structure destroy function then ?

Comment: @PBragg I don't think there is some general reason why this would not work. Please post a new question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should be able to find out the exact line where the crash occurs using a debugger.

Comment: @PBragg Are you maybe double-destroying or freeing the same object?

Comment: you are absolutely right, some of the texture objects in the fields are not properly initialized and never used in the code, causing the crash.